# Basic Python 2.7 Math Script (4 variables and 3 consecutive math operations)

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

I'm still starting to learn Python on my own and I need to write a script that asks the user for 4 numbers and then it lets the user choose which math operations it is going to perform with the chosen numbers. I already defined the math operations functions and asked the user for the numbers and set variables with them:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    return a / b

x = float(raw_input('Choose your first number\n> '))

y = float(raw_input('Choose your second number\n> ' ))

z = float(raw_input('Choose your third number\n> '))

w = float(raw_input('Choose your fourth number\n> '))
```

Now I need to ask the user which operations he would like to perform in order of choice like:
If he says add then the script adds x + Y, if for the second operator he says multiply the scripts then multiply the sum of (x+y) by z and if for the third operator he says divide the script  takes ((x+y)*z) and divide it by w.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Have you tried something that isn't working?

Comment: I don't know how to set a variable with the choice of operator. I already tried to use if response = add/divide... return add(x, y) and so on. But it got too big and not useful at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, I would ask a user what operation he wants to go with:

```
math_option =raw_input('Choose the math operation: ')
```

and later on check what option was chosen:

```
if math_option == "add":
    print add(x, y)
if math_option == "multiply":
     add_num = add(x,y)
     mul_num = multiply(math_option,z)  
     print mul_num
```

and so on

Comment: Thanks for the help!